# Converting boost std::string::const_iterator to string and int c++

Tags: c++, regex, boost, casting

I need to convert const_iterator into a type that I can do int and string operations to.
results[1] contains the text from the regex_search that I need to work with.
I've spent a couple hours already trying cast into a workable format, no success...

```
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
      boost::regex ex(pattern, boost::regex::perl);
      if(boost::regex_search(line, results, ex))
        (results[1] > 10) ? cout << "Fail" : cout << "Pass";
```

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an `std::string` out of a match result of const string iterators like this:

```
std::string result_string( results[1].first, results[1].second );
```

...or simply:

```
std::string result_string = results[1].str();
```

You can coerce the string to an `int` like this:

```
int result_int = boost::lexical_cast< int >( result_string );
```

...or, as pointed by *@Jonathan Wakely*, if you are using **C++11**:

```
int result_int = std::stoi( result_string );
```

Comment: why not `std:stoi()` instead of `lexical_cast`?

Answer (score 3):

`results[1].first` is an iterator that points to the beginning of the text that matched; `results[1].second` is an iterator that points past the end of the text that matched. Use this pair of iterators to access individual characters in the match. If you just want a string object that holds a copy of the matched text, use `results[1].str()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the first and second methods, I was noticing them on my searching but didnt quit grasp their ideo clearly.

Comment: `first` and `second` are not functions; they're data members.